# Javascript quick array declaration

Tags: javascript, perl, arrays

Is there a Javascript equivalen of Perl's qw() method to quickly create arrays ?
i.e.

```
in Perl @myarray = qw / one two three /;
in Javascript var myarray = ('one', 'two', 'three' );  // any alternative??
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To ‘quickly’ write an array, you can do this:

```
var x = 'foo bar baz'.split(' ');
```

Especially for large arrays, this is slightly easier to type than:

```
var x = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
```

Although obviously, using `.split()` is much less performant than just writing out the entire array.

Comment: IMHO, the first method is bad form.  There's no need to spend unnecessary execution time *every time* the script is ran just to save yourself some key strokes *once*.

Comment: IMHO, maintainability and readability trumps an extremely minor increase in execution time.

Comment: @Justin Johnson: Exactly! That’s why I recommend typing the whole array out instead.

Comment: @rjh What's unmaintainable or unreadable about syntnax as overly common as literal array declaration?

Comment: @Justin: a qw()-style function is easier to read and, since IE doesn't support trailing commas in literal array declarations, it's easier to add or remove new items without creating a syntax error. Even if the advantages are minimal, I think this kind of syntax optimisation is pointless unless the construct is inside a tight loop.

Comment: IMHO, it's silly to consider array literals anything but easy to read, easy to use, and all-around friendly.  Also, using array literals is not an optimization, using a qw-style function is pessimization.

Answer (score 5):

There is not a built in construct, but you can do either of the following:

```
var myarray = 'one two three'.split(' '); // splits on single spaces
```

or

```
function qw (str) {return str.match(/\S+/g)}

var myarray = qw(' one two  three '); // extracts words
```

Comment: Why `.split(/\s+/)` and not `.split(' ')`? The latter appears to be faster.

Comment: @Mathias => Perl's `qw//` operator will split on variable width whitespace. I've updated my answer to include the faster single char split, and a `qw` clone

Comment: Cool, I didn’t know `qw//` worked like that. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score -2):

```
var array:Array = [ 1 , 2 , 3 ];
var dictionary:Object = { a:1 , b:2 , c:3 };
```

Comment: it does not compile (in FF at least). I can do var array = [ 1, 2, 3];
but not var array = [ one, two, three ].

Comment: Quote your strings:  `var array = [ 'one', 'two', 'three' ]`

Comment: @Nikki I think the point is that he *doesn't* want to quote every single string.

Comment: In javascript, you have to quote strings unless they are object field names.  An array can be initialized with numbers, strings, arrays, or objects.

var array:Array = [ 1, "two", [1,2,3], { value:4 }];
var dictionary:Object = { one:1, two:"two", three:[1,2,3], four:{value:4}};